# Physics Simulation Ensuring Circles Do Not Overlap - C# XNA 4.0

Tags: c#, vector, physics

Okay, so I am trying to simulate the collision of balls on a 2-Dimensional plane. I can detect the collisions pretty easily using a simple comparison of positions and the sum of radii, however, sometimes the simulation gets ahead of itself and the circles overlap, which plays havoc with the rest of the simulation.

So I have figured that finding the normal vector between the two circles at the point of contact and adding onto the position vectors in that direction is what I need to do basically, and luckily I had a similar algorithm handling the velocity changes due to collisions so I adapted it thusly:

```
Vector2 normal = orgA.getCenterPosition() - orgB.getCenterPosition();
Vector2 tangent = new Vector2((normal.Y * -1), normal.X);

float diff = (orgA.getRadius() + orgB.getRadius()) - normal.Length();

normal.Normalize();

float PAn = Vector2.Dot(normal, orgA.position);
float PAt = Vector2.Dot(tangent, orgA.position);

PAn += diff;

float PBn = Vector2.Dot(normal, orgB.position);
float PBt = Vector2.Dot(tangent, orgB.position);

PBn -= diff;

Vector2 PA = (PAn * normal) + (PAt * tangent);
Vector2 PB = (PBn * normal) + (PBt * tangent);

orgA.position = PA;
orgB.position = PB;
```

The trouble is that when I run the simulation, and two balls meet, the whole thing goes crazy and they're suddenly going all over the shop.

Can anyone see the flaw in my algorithm? I've looked at it loads and I still can't find what's causing this.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with your algorithm? I don't fully get the purpose and therefore don't understand what exactly "the whole thing goes crazy" means. You found the diff which would be 0 when the balls touch and negative when they overlap but what's then?

Comment: This is a very common problem in physics simulations. If your time-step is large enough (or your objects travel fast enough) you will detect your collision too late (or not detect it at all!). 
This means your simple logic of collision response will almost certainly be wrong. The only case where it works is when by chance your objects touch at the time-step. Symptoms of this range from: tunnelling (objects miss each other), objects stick to each other, objects react violently upon contact.

Answer (score 0):

Hey buddy i think what you need is a loop. Its going crazy because once the balls touch they are constantly being upgraded with a new logic....

im not amazing at this but try putting the collision in a loop... should look something like this:

```
if ( diff < (orb radius))
{
Vector2 PA = (PAn * normal) + (PAt * tangent);
Vector2 PB = (PBn * normal) + (PBt * tangent);

orgA.position = PA;
orgB.position = PB;
}
```

something like that... I really hope this helps a little :/

from my understanding is this is in your update method, so keep in mind update runs constantly every millisecond... so its fine when your getting the difference between the spheres and sizes but after they collide and you you want them to move in a certain way you are calculating the same equation over and over...

Better yet make a bool such as isCollided and make sure you switch that true/false according to that statement

hope it helps i have an example project of collision if you want i can send it to you, samerhachem@hotmail.com